# sudo sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

Tags: linux, bash

I have written a bash script that goes to each machine and runs set of command. I am using the user iis that has sudo privlidges on that machine. However, when i run the sudo yum command i get sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo.

Not sure what is wrong ? I am using the -t command to force but it would still not work

bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=ccidetails.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read privateip password
do
echo $privateip
scp /home/Data/Test.c iis@$privateip:/tmp
sshpass -p$password </dev/null ssh -t -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" iis@$privateip "

hostname
cd /tmp
gcc Test.c -o TEST
./TEST
sudo yum -y update glibc
gcc Test.c -o TEST
./TEST
exit

" >> output.txt

done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Error:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

Comment: BTW, you have a bunch of bugs in here related to lack of quotes -- see what happens if you have a password with a space in it, for instance. Use `-p"$password"`, not `-p$password`. Similarly, quoting other expansions (such as `"iis@$privateip"` instead of `iis@$privateip`) will prevent other bugs -- in that particular case, for instance, you'd have failures if `IFS` contained the `.` character, or anything else that could be found in `$privateip`.

Comment: Also, `[ -f "$INPUT" ]`, not `[ -f $INPUT ]`, or else an empty value of `INPUT` becomes `[ -f ]`, which is equivalent to `[ -n -f ]`, which is always true. `[[ -f $INPUT ]]` is also safe, since `[[ ]]` has support from the bash parser (and suppresses string-splitting and glob expansion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this isn't a question for SO, you're almost there ... what you need to change is the number of -t  above ... try this:

```
sshpass -p$password </dev/null ssh -ttt -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" iis@$privateip "
```

Comment: I only see the following message on the terminal tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Comment: Why three? `-tt` should be sufficient to unconditionally allocate a TTY.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I had a few occasions in the past where -tt didn't work, -ttt never failed me.  Don't ask me for an explanation. ;}

Comment: See the source code: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh.c#L716 -- once you've had two `t`s, the only effect you can get from more is going back from `REQUEST_TTY_FORCE` to `REQUEST_TTY_YES`, which is what you get from only one. (This actually looks like a bug to me, as the behavior consistent with the docs would be to stay at `REQUEST_TTY_FORCE`).

Answer (score 8):

On remote host comment the line below on /etc/sudoers:

```
 grep tty /etc/sudoers
#Defaults    requiretty
```

That will allow you to continue. Make sure you understand the consequences of doing so:

```
man sudoers | grep -i requiretty  -A 5
       requiretty      If set, sudo will only run when the user is logged in
                       to a real tty.  When this flag is set, sudo can only be
                       run from a login session and not via other means such
                       as cron(8) or cgi-bin scripts.  This flag is off by
                       default.
```

If you don't want disable requiretty globally you can disable it for a specific user:

example:

```
Defaults    requiretty
Defaults:your_username_goes_here !requiretty
```

Comment: Thanks  looked into this but that is not the option i can consider.

Comment: You can instead of doing it globally you can define a user which is not required to be logged in

Comment: @user3846091I've just edited my answer showing how to disable requiretty for a single user

Comment: @user3846091, if you don't control the contents of `/etc/sudoers`, how are you avoiding the `sudo` invocation needing a password to proceed?